dyalog apl recognized idiom for `and` reduction
In Dyalog APL, could G be recognized as an idiom that evaluates to F since F is more efficient?
In order to do that maybe the interpreter first needs to know if it has a boolean array argument?
      G
 ∧/ ,
      F
~ 0 ∘∊ 
      v←¯1+∘?¨100 ⍴¨ 1e6⍴2
      cmpx 'F¨v' 'G¨v'
  F¨v → 1.7E¯1 |   0% ⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕           
  G¨v → 2.4E¯1 | +39% ⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕


Your F function returns a scalar, while G returns an boxed array, maybe you want to revise your question first?

Note the * in the cmpx result; your functions are not equivalent!

The spirit of my question is "why aren't we aggressive about extending the idiom list?" Don't we want naively expressed functions that "work" to execute like thoughtfully expressed functions that do the same thing?

The problem there is you start streching what expressions mean. Shouldn't what I type be executed? (Might be better to move to The APL Orchard if want to further discuss)

The short answer to your question is yes.
Dyalog could chose to extend the idiom list to include an "all ones" expression. An example of what you suggest does indeed occur - NA⊃¨⊂XV is implemented as XV[NA]
Idiom recognition happens in the scanner with usage decided at runtime, due to factors as such as type information and problems with stranding (eg. wanting to reject 1 0=⍴X)
